# docker-compose: how to create a file inside docker with custom user

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to add a custom user insider a docker image mapped with host user, then mount a volume and create some files on it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM dustynv/ros:humble-ros-base-l4t-r32.7.1

ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-mark hold '*opencv*' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt dist-upgrade -y  && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-pip \
    curl && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN if [ ${USER_ID:-0} -ne 0 ] && [ ${GROUP_ID:-0} -ne 0 ]; then \
    if getent group elgarbe ; then groupdel elgarbe; fi &&\
    groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} elgarbe &&\
    useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g elgarbe elgarbe &&\
    install -d -m 0755 -o elgarbe -g elgarbe /home/elgarbe &&\
    chown --changes --silent --no-dereference --recursive \
          --from=33:33 ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} \
        /home/elgarbe \
;fi

USER elgarbe

RUN echo "source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/install/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

WORKDIR ${HOME}/ws
RUN mkdir src
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  robot:
    network_mode: "host"
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-0}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-0}
    volumes:
      - ./ws:/home/elgarbe/ws:rw
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

Then running docker-compose up -d --build I get this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘src’: Permission denied
ERROR: Service 'robot' failed to build: The command '/bin/bash -c mkdir src' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

.env file:

```
; .env
USER_ID=1000
GROUP_ID=1000
```

But, if I comment out RUN mkdir src, then build the image and execute it I can run the command in the docker terminal without error.
What am I missing?

Thank